# Is this pattern for high trade prices in the NKE NYSE data correct?

Tags: time-series, intraday, analysis, data-mining, nyse

The question is whether the pattern described here actually exists in the NYSE historical data for NKE (Nike).

In over 63% of cases, `HighTradePrice` achieved between 15:36:00 and 15:41:59 increases by at least a factor of *0.00095682334649* compared to `HighTradePrice` achieved between 15:06:00 and 15:11:59 on the same day. Period: 2019 - 2021M09.

Source of data used to find this pattern: AlgoSeek’s Equity Trade and Quote Minute Bar excluding TRF. The term `HighTradePrice` is used according to the AlgoSeek definition = "Price of the highest trade".

Comment: What do you mean by correct?

Comment: If you look into NYSE data that you have available (I assume that you have), you can see this pattern as well.
I should probably have asked “can you confirm the pattern …”.